# Getting some css error while doing edit operation using PHP and Javascript.

Tags: javascript, php, css

I need one help.while i am clicking on `edit` button my data are fetching from DB and it should display inside text field but here i am getting some css related error like below.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
```

I am explaining my code below.

```
function selectProductCompany(value){
    if(value==1){
        document.getElementById("compid").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("proid").style.display="none";
    }
    if(value==0){
        document.getElementById("compid").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("proid").style.display="block";
    }
}



    <div style="width:24%; float:left; padding:10px;">Select Company/Product : 
    <select class="form-control" id="company_pro" name="company_pro" onChange="selectProductCompany(this.value)">

    <option value="">Select Company/Product</option>
    <option value="1" <?php  if($getcustomerobj->companypro == 1){ print 'selected'; }?>>Select Company</option>
    <option value="0" <?php  if($getcustomerobj->companypro == 0){ print 'selected'; }?>>Select Product</option>
     </select>
    <?php 
   if($getcustomerobj->companypro ==1){
    echo " <script type=\"text/javascript\"> $('#company_pro').change() </script> ";
    }
    ?>
    <div id="err_msg_name" style="font-size:12px; color:#FF0000; text-align: center;"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="width:24%; float:left; padding:10px; display:none;" id="compid">Select Company :
    <select class="form-control" id="company_id" name="company_id">
    <option value="">Select Company</option>
    <?php
                                                $compdata=$db->kf_company_profile->find();
     foreach($compdata as $c){
     ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $c['_id']; ?>" <?php if($getcustomerobj->company_id == $c['_id'] or $_REQUEST['company_id'] == $c['_id']){ print 'selected'; } ?>><?php echo $c['cname']; ?></option>                         
    <?php } ?>
     </select>
       <div id="err_msg_name" style="font-size:12px; color:#FF0000; text-align: center;"></div>
     </div>
```

When my first drop down list will get value then the change event will fire and the javascript function is executing and i am getting the error in this `document.getElementById("compid").style.display="block"` line.Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: `getElementById` fails to find DOM element. Put JavaScript scripts before closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: Probably means that there's no element with the id "compid"

Comment: I dont see any element with the id of `compid` in your code. Perhaps it should be `company_id`, but im not sure, because html/php/js soup it a nightmare to read...

Comment: @Matheno but it's there in the code.

Comment: Please use a lint to format (spacing etc) your code blocks before you put them on SO, makes people who are trying to help you lives easier. For example this :https://infohound.net/tidy/

Comment: Do a view page source of the generated html page in browser. Look for `compid`, is it there? I suspect compid would be a number, you can not search by variable name, only value on generated page.

Comment: check the post again `<div style="width:24%; float:left; padding:10px; display:none;" id="compid">` `compid` is already there.

Answer (score 0):

`proid` is missing from your structure. Try to add it into the div containing the company product selector, like this:

```
<div style="width:24%; float:left; padding:10px;" id="proid">
```

Answer (score 0):

So I structured the code a bit and stripped the PHP for testing purposes, and all is working fine, except `proid` is missing.

```
<script>
    function selectProductCompany(value) {
        if (value == 1) {
            document.getElementById("compid").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("proid").style.display = "none";
        }
        if (value == 0) {
            document.getElementById("compid").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("proid").style.display = "block";
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
    #selectcompany {
        width: 24%;
        float: left;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    #err_msg_name {
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #FF0000;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #compid {
        width: 24%;
        float: left;
        padding: 10px;
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<div id="selectcompany">Select Company/Product :
    <select class="form-control" id="company_pro" name="company_pro" onChange="selectProductCompany(this.value)">

        <option value="">Select Company/Product</option>
        <option value="1">Select Company</option>
        <option value="0">Select Product</option>
    </select>

    <div id="err_msg_name"></div>
</div>

<div id="compid">
    Select Company :

    <select class="form-control" id="company_id" name="company_id">
        <option value="">Select Company</option>
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>

    <div id="err_msg_name"></div>
</div>
```